# Get a particular frame by time value using AVAssetReader

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avasset, avassetreader

I have checked this http://www.7twenty7.com/blog/2010/11/video-processing-with-av-foundation to get a video frame by frame. But my real requirement is to get a frame at particular time. I know that it should be possible by `AVAssetReader`, I wonder is there any direct method for this in `AVAssetReader`. Please give any guidance on how can I get frame at particular time.

I checked the `AVAssetImageGenerator` but this is not the thing I really wanted.

Finally I found the answer, you have to use timeRange property. Thats the only way for this.

Comment: What problem you're facing with `AVAssetImageGenerator` ? And if you found the solution for this then please post as answer to this question (instead of edit the question). That would be much helpful for future readers.

Comment: @Hemang I have posted my answer. What I want was I will get a timestamp of a frame and I need to pass that frame. AVAssetImageGenerator is for getting thumb images kind of things. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got an answer for this. I am posting my solution here, hope it helps some one.

Use AVAssetReader timeRange property for selecting frames in any time range.If you are looking for particular frame just provide start and end time as same.

Two things you need to keep in mind:

1.once you call AVAssetReader startReading method you cannot reset timeRange.

2.You have to recreate AVAssetReader for this, using stopReading method also really won't help.

This link might be also really useful, I found all these very helpful:)
[How to seek within an audio track using avassetreader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508619/how-to-seek-within-an-audio-track-using-avassetreader)