# How to implement a camera taking GIF in iOS?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I want to implement such a function that enable users to make GIF directly from their camera.

In detail, I want to show users a camera view, and a record button. When the button is tapped, the camera starts to record video. In fact, however, behind the scene the camera is actually taking photos at constant speed, say 1 shot per 0.5 second. When the record ends, we got an array of images and then connect them into a GIF.

I think there might be 2 approaches:

1、Directly taking images: Use AVCaptureStillImageOutput's -captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection method. But it will block UI every time it is called.

2、Take a video and extract several images from it. I have checked video taking libraries such as [PBJVision](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision) and [SCRecorder](https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder), and noticed that taking video is typically writing data to a mp4 file locally. I cannot figure out how to extract images at specific time intervals from a video file. Also, is there a way to store the video in memory?

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Creating Gif
[Create and and export an animated gif via iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915138/create-and-and-export-an-animated-gif-via-ios)
[Convert Images to gif using ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996690/convert-images-to-gif-using-ios)

Extract Images from Video
[Get a particular frame by time value using AVAssetReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045042/get-a-particular-frame-by-time-value-using-avassetreader)

Similar here Creating a Movie from Images
[How do I export UIImage array as a movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library called 'Regift' by Matthew Palmer, which will convert video to GIF.

Here it is: https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Regift

You can also check out the following answer here on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28150109/3288936

Hope this will help! :)